# Не могу создать массив в js с выходными данными

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Задача: Функція getOutdated приймає масив роботів robots і повертає масив індексів для роботів, у яких core_version менший за нову версію newVersion ПЗ.

Приклад:

```
const robots = [{core_version: 9}, {core_version: 13}, {core_version: 16}, {core_version: 9}, {core_version: 14}];

getOutdated(robots, 10) === [0, 3]
getOutdated(robots, 14) === [0, 1, 3]
getOutdated(robots, 8) === []
getOutdated(robots, 18) === [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Вопрос: в консоль мне сбоку (на фото) выводит правильные индексы, но я никак не могу собрать их в один массив, чтобы вывести, что я делаю неправильно и как доделать?

Мое решение сейчас :

```
function getOutdated(robots, newVersion) {
  //let number = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < robots.length; i++) {
    //console.log(robots[i]);

    if(robots[i].core_version < newVersion) {
      console.log(robots.indexOf(robots[i]));
    }
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getOutdated(robots, newVersion) {
  let results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < robots.length; i++) {
    if(robots[i].core_version < newVersion) {
      results.push(i);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

const robots = [{core_version: 9}, {core_version: 13}, {core_version: 16}, {core_version: 9}, {core_version: 14}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(getOutdated(robots, 10))); // === [0, 3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(getOutdated(robots, 14))); // === [0, 1, 3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(getOutdated(robots, 8))); // === []
console.log(JSON.stringify(getOutdated(robots, 18))); // === [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

if(robots[i].coreVersion < newVersion) {
results.push(i);

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]